# Calling ASP.NET MVC3 Razor Url.Action in partial automatically appends id when reloading in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I have an ASP.NET MVC page with multiple partial sections. Each of these sections has a script initialization and each be refreshed as a partial from itself.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var section1Config = {
            AddEditSection1Url: "@Url.Action("AddEditSection1", "Loan")"
        };
    });
</script>
```

On initial load, this renders like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var section1Config = {
            AddEditSection1Url: "/Loan/AddEditSection1"
        };
    });
</script>
```

When I refresh that partial section, the Url.Action includes the id that I passed in through AJAX without me asking it to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var section1Config = {
            AddEditSection1Url: "/Loan/AddEditSection1/2"
        };
    });
</script>
```

Here's the call on the client side I'm making:

```
$.post('/Loan/AddEditSection1/2', function (data) {
    $('#loanadd-1').html(data);
});
```

And here's the server side code that's called by that jQuery post:

```
public PartialViewResult AddEditSection1(int id)
{
    var viewModel = GetPopulatedAddEditViewModel(id);
    return PartialView("Partials/AddEditSection1", viewModel);
}
```

Any clue as to why the render engine is being so "helpful"? It's really making things unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: any reason you do not just remove @Url.Action and hard code the URL?

Comment: @Daveo You should avoid hardcoding URLs in MVC wherever possible

Comment: @Chao Why? My code "/Loan/AddEditSection1" is so much more readable and less platform dependant. If I want to swap my server side code to anther technology I do not have to rewrite my JavaScript. What benifit does using Url.Action give other then making it harder to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of the time you will actually find this behaviour quite useful, in fact you're used to it already, notice that often you will call `Url.Action` or `Html.Action` without your contrller name, it's all part of the same parameter provider.

Anyway, in situations where you explicitly don't want to include a parameter just pass in an object and set it to nothing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var section1Config = {
        AddEditSection1Url: "@Url.Action("AddEditSection1", "Loan", new {id=""})"
    };
});
</script>
```

Comment: To a degree that makes sense, but it doesn't explain why that gets appended ONLY to that Url.Action and not to the others I'm setting up. I left the others out for clarification, but  they don't end up working the same way.

For instance, 

    AddLoanProfileAmortizationUrl: "@Url.Action("AddLoanProfileAmortization")"

Renders the same way every time. Why does it work differently in the other case?